# Menu that conditionally shows webform, or edit previous submission

Tags: routes, webforms, redirection

How can I have a menu item "RSVP" that shows a webform, but after an authenticated user has submitted that webform, clicking on "RSVP" would now bring them back to their submission in edit mode?

rsvpdirect.info:

```
name = rsvpdirect
description = "Redirects webform nodes to edit if the user has already submitted it once before."
package = Custom
core = 7.x
files[] = rsvpdirect.module
```

rsvpdirect.module:

```
<?php

/**
* @file
* Forces redirect of webform node to edit the user's previous submission.
*
*/

/**
* Implementation of hook_node_view()
*/
function rsvpdirect_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  global $user;
  if ($node->type == 'webform' && $view_mode == 'full' && arg(0) == 'node') {
    $submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid' => $node->nid, 'uid' => $user->uid));
    $submission_count = webform_get_submission_count($node->nid, $user->uid);

 if ($submission_count >= 1) {
      // Get first submission
      $submission = reset($submissions);
      drupal_goto('node/' . $node->nid . '/submission/' . $submission->sid . '/edit');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [hook_node_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and redirect functionality to redirect if webform is submitted. Your menu link always point to webform page.

```
function YOURMODULENAME_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  global $user;
  if ($node->type == 'webform' && $view_mode == 'full' && arg(0) == 'node') {
    $submissions = webform_get_submissions(array('nid' => $node->nid, 'uid' => $user->uid));
    $submission_count = webform_get_submission_count($node->nid, $user->uid);
    if ($submission_count >= 1) {
      // Get first submission
      $submission = reset($submissions);
      drupal_goto('node/' . $node->nid . '/submission/' . $submission->sid . '/edit');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've installed the module with source code (included now in my question) and when I visit domain.com/rsvp1 (the name of my webform) it gives me a page that has an error box indicating: You have already submitted this form.

Comment: Post your .module code here to investigate...

Comment: it's in my original question now.. I don't know how to post code in this comment section. Look up ^

Comment: Can you clear cache and try ? Which version of Drupal are you using ?

Comment: v7.26. I just noticed rsvpdirect enable checkbox for the module won't stay enabled. I must have made a typo somewhere..